# jQuery SlideToggle on checkbox

Tags: jquery

I currently have this working with a button.  How do I switch display/hide to work with a Checkbox?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `change` event

```
$('.show_hide').change(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
 });
```